# Considerations for prepping breaded chicken for freezing

Tags: freezing, breadcrumbs, breading

I have chicken breasts. I want to cut into strips, bread, freeze and later bake or fry. The binder will be egg. The breading will be semolinia bread crumbs. There will be parmesan and italian herbs in the breading. Any special considerations compared to breading with the intention of cooking immediately?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are special considerations for the actual breading procedure. I think the most important considering is to individually freeze the breaded chicken strips. I'd place them on parchment, on a sheet pan, and freeze them. Then after they are frozen, bag them for later use. IQF (individually quick frozen) pieces are less likely to stick together. This is particularly important with breaded chicken, where the breading will fall off if it sticks to another, leaving you with inconsistently breaded chicken strips.

Answer (score 2):

I would freeze the chick first, individually. Egg & Bread them after freezing will make the stuff stick and it will generally freeze quickly.  Then you can place them back in the freezer. It should be a quick process so you won't thaw the meat while doing this. And what Andy said.  I do this with my poppers, freezing them makes the breading stick better.